# Regenerate NSManagedObject subclasses on build

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have searched a bit but I cannot find an easy way to tell xcode to regenerate all the `NSManagedObject` subclasses on build. I would do this to be able to take all those classes off our git repository and only committing the model, and at the same time be sure that no one runs into problems because the classes are not in sync with the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use something like mogenerator (http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator) to generate your model classes, you can get it to run as a script as per above suggestion.

This way, every time you trigger a build, the mogenerator script will run first making sure your classes have been updated according to the object model file.

Here's a good article to guide you through it http://www.esenciadev.com/2011/05/mogen-and-xcode4-integration/

Comment: just looked at the document it seems to be doing what I need. Thanks! I am going to test it over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a run script.

Select your target and then select "Build Phases". From the "Add Build Phase" button in he lower right choose "Add Run Script".

No write a shell script, perhaps invoking an AppleScript or Automator script that instructs Xcode to generate the files. I have looked at the Dictionary of Xcode (Choose Xcode with "Open Dictionary" from the AppleScript Editor), and there are hooks select the entities in your data model. I did not see a way via AppleScript to generate the files, but you could have it choose the corresponding menu item.

This is quite a little project. Please share your code once you got it to work.

Comment: Guess I was to lazy to write it by myself ;-) Seems like mogenerator above does that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script that generates NSManagedObject subclasses like Xcode does (classes and categories).

[cdgenerator](https://github.com/shirerom/cdgenerator)

It is very easy to use.